# How to create Whatsapp like notifications layout in iOS (user icon instead of app icon)?

Tags: ios, push-notification

[image: push notification with user icon instead of app icon]

Hi all, how can I add Whatsapp like push notifications to my app?
I want to display push with custom layout/icon.

I've searched iOS documentation without success, all I've found is not what I'm searching for.
The notification icon is always the app icon, but in my app I what to display the user icon and not my app icon.
How can this be done?
Tnx

Comment: Quick searching for `ios push notifications custom icon` ... Apple's docs on it can be found here: [Implementing communication notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/implementing_communication_notifications) ... search results seem to provide a bunch of articles / tutorials on it.